# Why need to use 'addChildViewController:' method

Tags: cocoa-touch

please explain me, why I need to use `addChildViewController:` method? 
After all, when I put subview to view `[some_obj.view addSubview:some_view]`, these subview knows about his controller.

Thanks.

Comment: The parent controller doesn't know about the new ViewController that you have just added so how does it know to forward life cycle events and rotation etc...

Comment: But, as say's in Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW2), view delivers events to view's view controller, if view can't handle event (responder chain).
If I have view in hierarchy, view can deliver events to view's view controller.

Comment: The parent controller doesn't know about the new view Controller. E.g. the parent controller doesn't know that it needs to forward on it's lifecycle events like `viewDidLoad` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addChildViewController`

Needs to be called, cause the parent controller needs to hold a reference to its child view controller for lifetime / background management... this reference cannot / shouldn't be  obtained from UIView, when added as a subview

Also you can than reference parent from the child via `self.parentViewController`

Apple Says about `addChildViewController`

> Adds the given view controller as a child. If the new child view
>   controller is already the child of a container view controller, it is
>   removed from that container before being added. This method is only
>   intended to be called by an implementation of a custom container view
>   controller. If you override this method, you must call super in your
>   implementation.

For adding / removing, you can refer to this great category and have no worry when to call it:

[UIViewController + Container](https://github.com/xelvenone/UIViewController--Container-)

```
- (void)containerAddChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController {

    [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
    [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}

- (void)containerRemoveChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController {

    [childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [childViewController removeFromParentViewController];

}
```